# small problem with the implementation of a video in html

Tags: html, css

I implemented a video in my html code but just the iframe tag in the div tags and not video and i intend to add a lazy image on this video

```
<div class="video" style="padding: 56.25% 0 0 0; position: relative;" poster="../../assets/images/banner1.jpg">
    <iframe
        src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/816485409?h=b26fcc260f&amp;loop=1&amp;controls=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;player_id=0&amp;app_id=58479"
        frameborder="0"
        allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture"
        allowfullscreen
        style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"
        title="video1.mp4"
    ></iframe>
</div>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you describe what the problem actually is? I'm not at all clear.

Comment: in fact my code works very well, I ask for help mainly to be able to put a lazy image while the preloading of the video